# Format string exploit using short writes: 4 bytes off

Tags: c, linux, exploit

In Jon Erickson's book Hacking: The Art of Exploitation, he wants to write 0xbffffd72 to some value that exists at 0x08049794. So he goes...

```
./fmt_vuln $(printf "\94\x97\x04\x08"%x%x%x%hn

...

test_val @ x08049794 = -65515 0xffff0015
```

15 is the number of bytes written so far.

Then he subtracts 8 from 0xfd72 for the first short and gets 64874. Why does he subtract 8 and not 15 or some other number?

And after he subtracts 0xfd72 from 0x1bfff to get 49805.

Then he does

```
./fmt_vuln $(printf "\94\x97\x04\x08\96\x97\x04\x08")%64874x%4\$hn%49805x%5\$hn
```

And then he gets the correct result of 0xbffffd72.

But when I did

```
./fmt_vuln $(printf "\94\x97\x04\x08")%64874x%4\$hn
```

I got 0xfffffd6e. I don't know why I got fd6e instead of fd72.

Comment: The offset is likely the size of the 'stack frame' for the function, or thereabouts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, How can I check to see if that's the case?

Comment: Doesn't the book explain it?  It should.

Comment: oh, i found out why. 64874 is the value of the two first bytes of the address i want minus the 8 bytes of the address that I write with printf. If I only printf 4 bytes of the address, then I will be off by 4 bytes when I use the same 64874.  And no, the book doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that anyone runs into the same problem, the value of 64874 is the value calculated to get to the first two bytes of the address. So it's 0xfd72 - 8 = 64874. He subtracts 8 because there are four bytes of the address written via the printf command. When I try to run the same thing with only four bytes printed via the printf, then it's off by four bytes because four less bytes were written.